# Add sub tag into XML_VAR using FOR XML PATH resultset

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, path

I try with a unique query to get a @xml_var with sub tag..but I've never done for a resulset of this king. Can someone give me some tip to get the right results?
Thnaks ALEN, Italy

**FROM**

```
 DECLARE @xml_var XML  
    SET @xml_var =  (
                SELECT 
                    nRiga as LineNumber,
                    nRiga as BuyersOrderLineReference,
                    skuFornitore as SuppliersProductCode,
                    '' as BuyersProductCode,
                    FR.quantita as Amount
                FROM Testate FT
                JOIN Righe FR
                       ON (FT.idOrdine = FR.idOrdine AND FR.idStato <> 'A')
                --WHERE FT.idOrdine = @idOrdine
                WHERE ft.idOrdine = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
                Order by fr.nRiga
                FOR XML PATH('OrderLine')
                )
    SELECT @xml_var
```

**my result is like...**

```
<OrderLine>
<LineNumber>1</LineNumber>
<BuyersOrderLineReference>1</BuyersOrderLineReference>
<SuppliersProductCode>PTN-9050</SuppliersProductCode>
<BuyersProductCode />
<Amount>2</Amount>
</OrderLine>
```

**I need something like...**

```
<OrderLine>
    <LineNumber Preserve="true">1</LineNumber>
    <OrderLineReferences>
        <BuyersOrderLineReference Preserve="true">1</BuyersOrderLineReference>
    </OrderLineReferences>
    <Product>
        <SuppliersProductCode>PTN-9050</SuppliersProductCode>
        <BuyersProductCode></BuyersProductCode>
    </Product>
    <Quantity>
        <Amount>2</Amount>
    </Quantity>
</OrderLine>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following hard coded example returns the XML you seem to need:

It should be rather easy to get the values out of your tables instead.

Things might be different, if there is `1:n`-data where I assume `1:1` data...

```
SELECT 'true' AS [LineNumber/@Preserve]
      ,1 AS LineNumber
      ,(
        --I assume this is 1:n
        SELECT 'true' AS [BuyersOrderLineReference/@Preserve]
              ,1 AS BuyersOrderLineReference
        FOR XML PATH('OrderLineReferences'),TYPE
       )   
       ,'PT-9050' AS [Product/SuppliersProductCode]
       ,'' AS [Product/BuyersProductCode]
       ,2 AS [Quantity/Amount]
FOR XML PATH('OrderLine');
```

The result

```
<OrderLine>
  <LineNumber Preserve="true">1</LineNumber>
  <OrderLineReferences>
    <BuyersOrderLineReference Preserve="true">1</BuyersOrderLineReference>
  </OrderLineReferences>
  <Product>
    <SuppliersProductCode>PT-9050</SuppliersProductCode>
    <BuyersProductCode></BuyersProductCode>
  </Product>
  <Quantity>
    <Amount>2</Amount>
  </Quantity>
</OrderLine>
```

Comment: Thanks very much! GREAT! It's what I need... now I study this code... for learning my future implementation